# WebDAV ignores permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, explorer-view, webdav

Here's an interesting question, regarding WebDAV ("Open with Explorer") in SharePoint 2013 Foundation.

We have some old content on our site that will be deleted soon, but in the meantime I have changed permissions on the old lists and libraries so most staff don't see them.

However, it appears that (some or all) regular users are seeing the old lists and libraries, even though their permissions should "trim" those lists and libraries.

Any thoughts on why that might be?
Thank you,
Gerry